# JHipster update configuration at runtime

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I have a java service created using JHipster Generator ver 3.4.0 using the monolith approach. How can I use @RefreshScope? Is it just a matter of brining in spring-cloud as dependency and annotating with bean @RefreshScope?

Does the JHipster Configuration UI support updating configuration values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it just a matter of brining in spring-cloud as dependency and annotating with bean @RefreshScope?

You can add spring cloud dependencies partially, so yes. You can generate a microservice application to see how this should be configured properly by taking a look at bootstrap.yml

> Does the JHipster Configuration UI support updating configuration values?

I believe you are talking about the JHipster Registry. The purpose of this UI is to show you an aggregated configuration, which is efficiently loaded for some application. This is not really part of spring cloud config. The only 2 ways are filesystem or git repository.

But we are currently working on integrating consul as config solution as well. Consul itself does provide an UI to change config on the fly